# does it make sense to test mongoose models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, model, mongoose

I'm new to testing in general and although i see some projects like meanjs or ghost testing their models, some of it doesn't make much sense to me.

For instance, I've seen some people do something like this:

```
it( 'should create a new group', function( done ) {
      utils.fixtures.createGroup()
        .then( function( group ){
          group.should.exist;
          done();
        }).catch( function( err ){
          done(err);
        });
    });
```

Which looks to me like they are testing mongoose instead of testing their own code.
If the model contains custom validation methods, etc, it makes perfect sense to test that.

So my question is if it makes any sense to test anything related to the model unless it's a schema method/hook ?

Comment: Still good to test features used within Mongoose. It's been known to have bugs in new version that have caused production issues in the past. Don't always trust open source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it still makes sense to test basic model construction if only to reveal potential breaking changes should someone attempt to merge in work which messes with models. If your application assumes that certain models exist… it is good to find out right away if that changes, no? And if the change is deliberate, then it is the onus of the author to make sure all tests will pass post-merge.